# Intersecting semi circle and quarter circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I'm stumped. I came across this question on Facebook and accidentally lost the suggestion before I could see the answer. I've spent hours on it...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please include in your question your thoughts and what you have tried.

Comment: $\text{(radius of quarter-circle)}=\sqrt{2}\text{(radius of semi-circle)}$, so $\text{(area of quarter-circle)}=\text{(area of semi-circle)}$

Answer (score 0):

Taking the origin at the bottom left corner of the figure, the parametric equation of the quarter circle (assuming the radius is $1$) is

$ p(t) = (\cos(t) , \sin(t) ) , \hspace{4pt} 0 \le t \le \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

At $ t = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ we have midpoint of the quarter circle, and at that point we have the peak of the semi-circle, hence the radius of the semi-circle is $ R = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4} ) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $

The area of the quarter circle is $\dfrac{1}{4} \pi $

The area of the semi-circle is $ \dfrac{1}{2} \pi \left( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2  = \dfrac{1}{4} \pi $

Since the areas of the quarter circle and the semi-circle are the same, then taking away the white area from each leaves equal areas.

Answer (score 0):

[image: OP with yellow triangle added in]

The trick is to add another shape, the yellow right triangle, so we can find the red and blue areas just by adding and subtracting divisions of shapes we already know (i.e. circle and right triangle)

Let the semi-circle have radius 1. This means the quarter-circle will have radius rt2.

The red area is equal to half the quarter-circle, plus the area of the yellow triangle, then minus half the semicircle... which, once you work it out, is 1/2.

The blue area is equal to half the semicircle, plus the yellow triangle, minus half the quarter-circle... which is likewise 1/2.

So all three colored regions have the same area.

Comment: This is assuming that the radius of the semi circle is equal to the side of the triangle, but how do we know that the intersection point is on the center of the semi circle?